# Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'xxx'@'%' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, csv

I am facing the below error while loading the csv file from s3 into MYSQL RDS database

```
Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'xxx'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

code used:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 's3://v222/Test/sample_data.csv' INTO TABLE <tablename>
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: Can't we use LOAD DATA command to load csv file data from s3 into mysql-rds db?. If yes, what kind of privileges should be provided here.